# How can I extract the newly added rows after SMOTE (imblearn module)

Tags: python, imblearn, smote

Is it possible to extract the newly added rows from  pandas dataframe that were created by imblearn's smote function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Apparently they are being appended at the end of the fit_resample returned dataframe:

my target is "DIED"

```
smotez = SMOTENC([10,11], random_state=555, k_neighbors=10)
smote_tomek = SMOTETomek(random_state=555, smote=smotez , n_jobs=-1)  
X_train_new, y_train_new = smote_tomek.fit_resample(X_train, y_train) 
train_data_new = pd.concat([X_train_new.iloc[1:],y_train_new],axis=1)
train_data_new.dropna(inplace=True)
smote_data = train_data_new.iloc[len(train_data)-1:,]
print("Y_train_smote:\n", npunique(smote_data['DIED']),smote_data['DIED'].mean())
```

As you can see, all rows are of the minority class ("DIED")

Y_train_smote:
 [[    1 91936]] 1.0

Double-checking, the expression below should return 0:

```
print(len(smote_data) + len(X_train) - len(X_train_new))
```

0